# Putting css borders around radio buttons

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a garish red border around some radio buttons, but it is not showing up in Firefox latest or Chrome latest.  Work fine in IE9/IE8.

Each of the input element on my form that are required has a data-val-required attribute put in by MVC3.  All browsers puts in the red borders just dandy when we have a text or textarea inputs, but am struggling with the radio button.  For IE, it works, but other browsers won't put the red border around it.

css:

```
input[data-val-required], select[data-val-required], textarea[data-val-required]
{
    background-color: #F0FFFF;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

view-source:

```
<label for="WaiveSelect">Do you waive confidentiality?</label><br />
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field WaiveSelect must be a number." data-val-required="Please select waive." id="WaiveSelect" name="WaiveSelect" type="radio" value="0" /> No, I do not waive confidentiality<br />
<input id="WaiveSelect_2" name="WaiveSelect" type="radio" value="2" /> Yes, I waive confidentiality<br />
<input id="WaiveSelect_3" name="WaiveSelect" type="radio" value="3" /> Yes, I waive confidentiality except to the client<br />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="WaiveSelect" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

What it looks like in IE (Firefox and Chrome shows no borders):
[image]

Comment: If you're open to doing the whole label and can stomach not-so-clean markup, here's one way to style them.  In this case I want it to be highlighted when required, but you can do the same thing when it's invalidated (class='error' vs [required]). http://jsfiddle.net/jinglesthula/tsahh2jg/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could accomplish by wrapping each input element with div tag and give it a border and a float left... like this:

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;float:left">
   <input type="radio".. />
</div>
No, I do not waive confidentiality
```

Answer (score 58):

```
input[type=radio]{
    outline: 1px solid red
}
```

Comment: `outline` is widely used by browsers to indicate focus. If you go with this, you may fail WCAG 2.0 web accessibility [Requirement 2.4.7](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#qr-navigation-mechanisms-focus-visible).

Answer (score 12):

I know this is four years old, but I came up with a nice solution using CSS Pseudo elements.

My requirement was to highlight an unchecked checkbox, or radio button in validation.

```
<input type="radio" class="required" name="radio1"/>

/* Radio button and Checkbox .required needs an after to show */
input[type=radio].required::after, input[type=checkbox].required::after {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    content: '';
    border: 2px solid red !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* Radio buttons are round, so add 100% border radius. */
input[type=radio].required::after {
     border-radius:100%;
}
```

Comment: I like about this approach that it doesn't require any additional HTML elements.

Comment: Can also use `:indeterminate` to highlight them when none in the group are checked

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers support borders around radio buttons and checkboxes. I voted for a bug years ago to have this included in Gecko but so far they haven't implemented it.

Comment: appears I may have to wrap it around a bunch of divs or something?  where may I vote? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This may help you:

```css
.style {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2px;
  background-color: #f0ffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="style">
  <input type="radio" />
</div>
<div class="style">
  <input type="radio" />
</div>
<div class="style">
  <input type="radio" />
</div>
<div class="style">
  <input type="radio" />
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rp9HJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Complete code using jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/xcb26Lzx/

```
$(function(){
      $('.layer').css('border',0);
    $('input:radio').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.layer').css('border','1px solid red');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Put a div around the input and assign a class to the div like so:

```
<div class="custom"><input type="radio"></div>
```

Then open your custom css file and add this CSS

```
.custom {border: 1px solid red; border-radius: 30px; padding: 3px 3px 0 3px; background: red;}
```

This should create a nice red border around the radio button. If you're using a check box you would simply remove the border-radius: 30px from the css. Depending you may need to play with the padding a bit to center the button, but this worked for me.

Edit: You will also want to assign the following CSS to the div so it lines up correctly.

```
.custom {display: inline;}
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hr0u2dcz/10/)