# Radio Button Selection in ASP.Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net application(points to framework 4.0) , when I select a radio button the selection border is coming only for radio button not for the text of radio button. 
please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you use 4.0 version on your deployment

check `section Framework Version` on your IIS

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
```

try using

```
outline: 1px solid #ff0000;
```

or you can refer this link

[Putting css borders around radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849626/putting-css-borders-around-radio-buttons)