# The :invalid pseudo class not getting set for radio buttons

Tags: css, html, radio-button

I have a radio group with required attribute. I'm trying to control the style of the radio group based on whether one input is selected or not. But it doesn't seem that :invalid works for radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:invalid` does in fact work with radio buttons. I think the issue is the styles you are adding just aren't being applied. In this fiddle you can see the two radio buttons I am targeting are spaced out a lot further than the other two. Upon clicking one of them they snap back to their original spacing:

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8j92ytdo/2/)

I would look into custom styling for radio buttons like this one: http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: A simpler way to see that `:invalid` works for radio buttons is to set `input:invalid { outline: solid red }`. My guess is that the OP tries to set a border on radio buttons, and *that* doesn’t work, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849626/putting-css-borders-around-radio-buttons

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Exactly! That led me to think `:invalid` doesn't work on radios...

Answer (score 1):

`:invalid` does not work for me, unless I set `required="required"` for at least one of the `<input name="group" type="radio">` tag.

Example:

```css
input:invalid {
  outline: 3px red solid;
}
```

```html
<input name="group" type="radio" value="1" required="required">
<input name="group" type="radio" value="2">
<input name="group" type="radio" value="3">
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question isn't all that clear,

maybe ':checked' can help ?