# Change border-color of radio button when selected

Tags: css, radio-button

I want to have a green radio button surrounded with a green border when I select it.
This is what I have:

```
input[type='radio'] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px gray;
    }

    input[type='radio']:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
        margin: 20% auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    input[type='radio']:checked:before {
        background: green;
    }

    .role {
        margin-right: 80px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .checkbox label {
        margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    }

    .roles {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
```

And the template:

```
<div class="roles">
    <input type="radio" name="role" value="ONE" id="one">
    <label class="role" for="one">ONE</label>
    <input type="radio" name="role" value="TWO" id="two">
    <label class="role" for="two">TWO</label>
</div>
```

Here is a Jsfiddle: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xy4dbv80/)
Like you can see the `border-color` never changes to green... I tried to add `border-color` property to no avail... How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You may find an explanation here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849626/putting-css-borders-around-radio-buttons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border around label if radio is checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150784/border-around-label-if-radio-is-checked)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to check your css. The border you got is created by box-shadow and not by a border:

here is a fiddle that is working. Have Fun

```css
input[type='radio'] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        outline: none;
        border: 3px solid gray;
    }

    input[type='radio']:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
        margin: 20% auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

 input[type="radio"]:checked:before {
        background: green;
        
    }
    
    input[type="radio"]:checked {
      border-color:green;
    }

    .role {
        margin-right: 80px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .checkbox label {
        margin-bottom: 20px !important;
    }

    .roles {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="roles">
    <input type="radio" name="role" value="ONE" id="one">
    <label class="role" for="one">ONE</label>
    <input type="radio" name="role" value="TWO" id="two">
    <label class="role" for="two">TWO</label>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem :) :)

Answer (score 4):

You could just update the `box-shadow` color:

```css
input[type='radio'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px gray;
}

input[type='radio']:checked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px green;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  margin: 20% auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type='radio']:checked:before {
  background: green;
}

.role {
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.checkbox label {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.roles {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="roles">
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="ONE" id="one">
  <label class="role" for="one">ONE</label>
  <input type="radio" name="role" value="TWO" id="two">
  <label class="role" for="two">TWO</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly, I misunderstood how works `box-shadow`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the answers above are correct, there is the easier way of achieving the same behaviour using [CSS `appearance: none` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance).

For example, if you'd like to change `border-color`, you can achieve it by using following combination:

```css
.radio {
  appearance: none;
  border-color: red;
}
```

Mind, that MDN docs says:

> Note: If you wish to use this property on websites, you should test it very carefully. Although [it is supported in most modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance#browser_compatibility), its implementation varies. In older browsers, even the keyword none does not have the same effect on all form elements across different browsers, and some do not support it at all. The differences are smaller in the newest browsers.

So while it is a very useful property to have for your custom radio buttons (and other standard UI elements which are controlled by the system UI by default), it should be thoroughly tested before pushing it to prod.